# How to use QT 4.6.3 Binding with Lazarus

Tags: qt, controls, qt4, widget, lazarus

Is there a way to use QT 4.6.3 visual controls with Lazarus 0.9.28.2 Beta?

How I can install the QT widgets and have them in my Controls pallete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Lazarus Wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Qt_Interface#Qt_4_Bindings), Qt support is a work in progress. There are bindings available but I don't get the impression that they support widgets on the palette. I have not used Lazarus so I may be incorrect.